# Executing one thread at a time sequentially

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have several threads being created in a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
   new Thread() {
       //do stuff
   }
}
```

but I need to make sure that these threads execute one after the other rather than all at the same time.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of the entire point of threads.

Comment: why you need thread in that case?

Comment: Threads are for when you need to do multiple tasks simultaneously. If that's not what you need, then don't use threads.

Comment: I understand it seems counter intuitive, but there is also other stuff going on that makes it require a thread.

Comment: If what you meant was that you want to execute them sequentially, use an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just create Runnables and submit them to a thread pool containing only 1 thread.

Comment: @JeanLogeart can you explain more?

Comment: @JDOdle Another solution would be to start the next task once the first is done. Like have thread 0 start thread 1, thread 1 start thread 2, etc.

Comment: Even if it requires _a_ thread, it doesn't require _five_ threads that are forced to run one after the other.

Comment: @Lalaland See my edit; That's a good idea.

Answer (score 9):

Use an `ExecutorService` with a pool size of 1 to execute your jobs  sequentially (clean and simple solution).

If you need a quick example:

```
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        final int idx=i;
        executor.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               System.out.println("I'm thread #"+idx); 
            }
        });
    }
```

This will execute 100 Runnable sequentially, and each one will print its index.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for more details.

Comment: _...to execute your threads..._  An ExecutorService does not execute _threads_.  It executes tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
   Thread a = new Thread() {
       //do stuff
   };
a.start();
a.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

I think thread join is what you want